# Can a Linux partition unnoticeably create files in another partition and, if, how can I prevent it?

Tags: security, partition, dual-boot

Is it possible that my Linux partition creates files in another partition with me not noticing it?

If yes, how to prevent it?

Background:
Manjaro partition encrypted, bootloader on Manjaro, **swap unit masked**.
The aim is to keep safe data encrypted in Linux and prevent any leak. As far as I know the only weak link in the chain is a [evil maid attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Maid_attack).

Comment: A partition doesn't create files. A process does... And how do you prevent the evil maid from suspending your protection?

Comment: @xenoid with partition I meant anything that conceptually is contained in the partition, like processes that happen while I'm in the partition's system. I'm supposed to avoid the evil maid ensuring that the only bootloader I'm writing a password into is the original one.

Comment: How do you ensure that you are booting on an unmodified kernel (UEFI?). How do you prevent the EM to connect a network (USB or Ethernet) on a running machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linux installation can only create files on partitions that are mounted.

So unless you `mount` unencrypted partitions into your system (or remote NFS-shares etc...), no, it won't create files "outside".

Be aware: Windows-partitions on your device can be mounted with a single mouse-click, depending on your exact setup.

Comment: At this point I can just be careful about possible programs that mount partitions or things in my current installation...